# What is p[a] for

Tags: homework

I am reading instructions for test on Monday, and I the example below:

```
A = {{1, -1, a + 1}, {2, -1, a}, {1, a + 2, 2 a + 3}}
X = {{x}, {y}, {z}}
B = {{0}, {3 - a}, {2 a + 1}}
p[a_] := Det[A]
p[a]
Solve[p[a] == 0, a]
```

I don't understand what the information ''p[a]'' is for? I get that  ''p[a_]'' defines the variable a '':='' is a new equal sign and ''Det[A]'' is what we seek. 
My instructions do not say why we have ''p[a]''.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Makes it easy assign and then find the determinant of `A` using that value of `a`.  For instance `p[6]` will return the determinant of `A` with `a=6`.

Comment: in the sequence of instruction in the code block, the first three assign symbols `A`,`X` and `B` with appropriate values; the fourth line performs a delayed assignment or what is equivalent in this case a function definition; the following, fifth line, when evaluated simply outputs the value of function `p` at `a`; this line does not add any new rule to the system-it just outputs the `Det` of matrix `A` at `a`. Finally, the last line in the code block, solves for the roots of the determinant of `A` in terms of `a`

Comment: If you feel like experimenting, evaluate `p[b]` and then reset by `Clear[A,p]` and re-define `A[a_]=rhs` where `rhs` as before and `p[a_]:=Det[A[a]]`; now evaluate `p[b]`; compare and contrast the two outputs.

Comment: this is horrible code. I suppose as a test exercise you are supposed to see that the pattern `a_` is never used on the right side of `p[a_]:=..`, so it doesn't matter what argument you supply to `p`. `Solve[p[x] == 0, a]` will give the same result

Comment: Have you run the code?

Comment: @user42582 I get ''Det[rhs]''...

Comment: george2079 and Daniel Lichtblau I tried to run the code without p[a] and with it, it gives me the same reply.
OH I see, it just write out the equation with variabel a, but we do not need it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Dovendyr `rhs` was intended as a shorthand for typing `{{1, -1, a + 1}, {2, -1, a}, {1, a + 2, 2 a + 3}}`; the full definition was supposed to be `A[a_]={{1, -1, a + 1}, {2, -1, a}, {1, a + 2, 2 a + 3}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I don't think this bit of code is an example of good Mathematica coding style. It would be better to have `p[a_] = Det[A]`, because that makes `p` a proper function of `a`. This in one of those few cases where immediate assignment makes good sense for a function definition. Compare the following:

```
Clear[p]
p[a_] = Det[A];
p[x]
p[1]

Out[33]= 8 + 6 x + x^2

Out[34]= 15

Clear[p]
p[a_] := Det[A];
p[x]
p[1]

Out[37]= 8 + 6 a + a^2

Out[38]= 8 + 6 a + a^2
```

The delayed assignment for `p` makes no real sense since it pretends to be a function definition, but isn't: `p` will just return the same polynomial in `a` regardless of what you put in.

Probably an even better way to all of this would be:

```
Clear[A, p]
A[a_] := {{1, -1, a + 1}, {2, -1, a}, {1, a + 2, 2 a + 3}};
p[a_] := Det[A[a]];
p[1]
p[x]

Out[59]= 15

Out[60]= 8 + 6 x + x^2
```

In this block of code, `a` is just a local symbol that's used to define the desired functional dependencies and which can be replaced by any other symbol later on.

Comment: It's not bad coding style, it's simply buggy code.

Comment: Well, given the fact that the last line that invokes `Solve` does actually result in the right answer, I was willing to give it some benefit of the doubt. But yes, you could easily argue that this is a bug that simply hasn't manifested itself yet.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now, It writes the equation instead of just giving what a values gives resultat 0.

Answer (score 2):

It simple prints `p[a]` so it can be seen in the output.

`SetDelayed` (:=) returns `Null` and thus doesn't print.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now!